# Graph: count cycles that include a node

Tags: algorithm, graph

I want to count the number of cycles a node in a non-directed graph belongs to.

These cycles can share nodes between them. Both of these would count:

```
A -> B -> A
A -> B -> C -> A
```

I've been trying my hand it for a while now. My current implementation counts cycles twice: walking them one way, then the other. It may have other bugs.

This is the recursive function to find paths (wrapped from `countCycles`):

```
function countPaths(current, destination, visited: set) ->
    if visited.contains(current):
        if current is destination and visited.size > 2:
            return 1
        else
            return 0

    visited.add(current)
    count = 0

    for each neighbor of current:
        count += countPaths(neighbor, destination)

    visited.remove(current)
    return count
```

If the only problem is that cycles are counted twice, I could just halve the result, but I would like to walk each cycle only once. The same algorithm may be good for something else.

Comment: the last paragraph is a true WTF.

Comment: If it were for me, I'd spend another hour going at this. My boss won't be so happy.

Comment: we cannot know what went wrong, show us your current (non-working) solution.

Comment: There it is, in pseudo-code

Comment: Your *algorithm* sounds correct, but your *code* may be faulty. If you decline to revisit a node because it was part of another cycle, then you're failing to erase marks correctly. If you're walking the same path more than once, then you're not doing the iteration over a node's neighbors correctly. Can you prepare a minimal example of either or both of these errors?

Comment: It's clear from the pseudo code. but to avoid confusion, you should mention that the cycle must not contain repeated nodes. in other words, a *simple cycle*. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)

Comment: @Beta he walks each cycle **exactly** twice because each cycle can be traverse in 2 different way. say, clock-wise or counter clock-wise.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ambiguous question. If a graph has cycles it can have an infinite number of paths in it.

In general, the all possible paths problem is NP hard and can have very large numbers of paths, even for small graphs.

The general strategy is to use breadth-first search in combination with a queue or some other mechanism that stores the visited nodes *only for the current branch*.

For more information see [all possible paths problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889918/finding-all-possible-paths-starting-between-a-specific-start-and-end)

Comment: the psuedo code impiles he only consider cycle with no repeated nodes --- a simple cycle.

Comment: Right, thats why I recommended using a data structure like a queue to remember which nodes have been visited on the current branch.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my `O(VE^2)` algorithm where `V` is the number of vertices and `E` is the number of edges. It is not a recursive algorithm.

I'll number the vertices from 1 to `V`. where 1 will always be the vertex in the question that must be present in counted cycle.

The sketch is:
I'll be counting the cycles inside smaller subset of all vertices and gradually add more vertex into consideration.
That is to say, start from the set `{1,2,3}`

Things you need to maintain:

1. `m[x][y]` a boolean table of size `V x V` remembering whether you
   have discovered a *simple path* through the vertex `1` that has `x`
   and `y` and end points of the path. by simple path I mean path
   without repeating vertices.
2. the count of cycle which is the answer

Let's start the algorithm.

```
(1) Initialize table `m` for the base case of set `{1,2,3}`. I'll assume you can do this.
(2) For each time you add a vertex `A` into consideration, do the following:

    (2.1) Update the cycle count

          For every (B,C) pair of vertices that are both adjacent to vertex A
          [Meaning we have a path (B,A,C)]
          that the table m has an entry of path (B,...,1,...,C)

          We can deduce that there is a simple cycle (A,B,...,1,...C,A).
          count it.

    (2.2) Update the table m

          For every vertex X that is adjacent to A and there is a path (X,...,1,...,Y)
          Remember that there is a path (A,...,1,...,Y) into table m.
```

algorithm description done.

Complexity analysis:
Outer loop goes through each vertex, so multiply a factor of `V`.
The step `(2.1)` goes through each pair of edges that are adjacent to `A`, so multiply a factor of `E^2`.
Overall `O(VE^2)`.

Comment: So, why the -1? Is my answer wrong or format incorrectly?

Comment: I could not improve on the algorithm in OP so that it doesn't traverse the same cycle twice. So, I gave a different algorithm that don't traverse same cycle twice. I don't think it's off-topic either.